# getting NULL values from Java regex Matcher with a found pattern

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to get the following regex to work on my String:

```
Pattern Regex = Pattern.compile("(?:(\\d+) ?(days?|d) *?)?(?:(\\d+) ?(hours?|h) *?)?(?:(\\d+) ?(minutes?|m) *?)?(?:(\\d+) ?(seconds?|s))?",
Pattern.CANON_EQ | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
Matcher RegexMatcher = Regex.matcher(myString);
while (RegexMatcher.find()) {
       ...
}
```

.. it basically splits a string like **1day 3 hours** into matched regex groups.

The problem I'm having is that when I get into the while loop, calls to `RegexMatcher.group(i)` will always return a `NULL` value, meaning they were not found in the string.

When I try to output `RegexMatcher.group(0)`, it returns an empty string, even though `myString` definitelly contains like `"hello 1d"` - which should return at least 1st group as `"1"` and second as `"d"`.

I've checked and double-checked the regex and it seems to be ok. No Idea what's wrong here.

Thanks for any ideas :-)

Comment: I have a suspicion that it's related to your non-capturing groups.

Comment: tried to remove all non-capturing groups as well as the Pattern.CANON_EX, Pattern.UNICODE_CASE and Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE flags to no avail

Comment: also tried to remove capturing groups within non-capturing groups and remove the big non-capturing groups altogether - no joy there

Comment: Hrmmm, don't think I'm going to be much help then :(.  Been quite a while since I've used regular expressions in Java and am not very familiar with the API.

Comment: no problemo, thanks for giving out that hint anyways ;-)

Comment: I experienced a similarly weird null in match groups. I didn't capture first part of regex as a group - that had an or in it. So I created a capture group for that - even though I wouldn't use it - and suddenly the other capture groups had data in them. To me that looks like a Java regex bug. See https://repl.it/repls/WigglyReflectingOs - try removing the parentheses around `(\\*{2}|\\*{4})` and (and changing groups to 1 and 2 from 2 & 3  see null gets returned)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a matcher `m`, input sequence `s`, and group index `g`, the expressions `m.group(g)` and `s.substring(m.start(g), m.end(g))` are equivalent.

Capturing groups are indexed from left to right, starting at one. Group zero denotes the entire pattern, so the expression `m.group(0)` is equivalent to `m.group()`.

If the match was successful but the group specified failed to match any part of the input sequence, then `null` is returned. Note that some groups, for example `(a*)`, match the empty string. This method will return the empty string when such a group successfully matches the empty string in the input.

If you want to ergodic all the matches, you can code like :

```
Pattern Regex = Pattern
            .compile(
                    "(?:(\\d+) ?(days?|d) *?)?(?:(\\d+) ?(hours?|h) *?)?(?:(\\d+) ?(minutes?|m) *?)?(?:(\\d+) ?(seconds?|s))?",
                    Pattern.CANON_EQ | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE
                            | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
    Matcher RegexMatcher = Regex.matcher("1 d 3 hours");
    while (RegexMatcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(RegexMatcher.group());
    }
```

**Note**: `m.group()` is equivalent to `m.group(0)`

Comment: Worth noting that half of that is from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(int)